# How to store API response in memory so I dont have to make http call each time component is load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to only once fill an array from fetching the data from an API and for the rest of the app life cycle unless users quit the app from both the foreground and background.

---

Currently I have a *component*:

***[My Code](https://pastebin.com/7fpdyKkA)***

I would like categories: `[]` not to fill everytime I go from one screen to another, is there anyway that I can save categories somewhere so I don't have to always fetch it, as the data are not changing from the API quite often!

Comment: Why don't you store it in a parent component and pass it down?

Comment: Run in within `componentDidMount` that runs only once. And depending on your needs pass it down to the children (that is after all one of the main concepts of react)

Comment: @Colin could you give some kind of examples?

Comment: You want it to be persistent between component mounts. Above options won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using redux with a library like this: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

This way you can re-hydrate the state from local storage.

Edit: Alternatively you can try to initiate the state from the data from local storage on your `constructor` and if you can't, then you can fetch data in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');

next page

var cat = localStorage.getItem("myCat");

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use out of the box solution you can go through with
 **AsyncStorage** https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

**Set Item**

```
try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
} catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
}
```

**Get Item**

```
try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
    if (value !== null){
        // We have data!!
        console.log(value);
    }
} catch (error) {
     // Error retrieving data
}
```